# I would like to replace air gap in my sink with a flat plate, what is that plate called?

Tags: plumbing, dishwasher

My sink currently has an air gap that my dishwasher is not connected to. Instead the plumber has the drain line going up and back down as shown in the first image below.

Since it is not being used, I would like to replace the air gap with just a flat plate (I already have a soap dispenser on the other side). What is that plate called? All my searches for air gap cap and variations just find air gap covers, not a flat plate replacement. Thx!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Kitchen Sink Hole Cover](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002ZAT0Z4)

The key is to search (Google is your friend) not based on "air gap" but based on what you are **actually** covering - a hole in the sink.

Comment: Argh, that does make sense in hindsight. Thanks!